# can't locate file for: -lPods-RestKit

Tags: ios, xcode

I updated my Xcode from version 6.1.1 to 7.3, and can no longer compile my project because of the errors below:

> error: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-RestKit
>
> error: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods-RestKit is not an object file (not allowed in a library)

I do not have much experience with ios development. Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because the lib does not exist or is not linked to your app, you can check if the lib exists first and then check if it is linked in your project build settings.